# AddLiquidity to Uniswap

Tags: uniswap, hardforks

I have been trying to addliquidity (Say DAI/WETH) on the Uniswap Rinkeby network to understand Uniswap better. I realized that it doesn't work well so I thought of deploying my contract on a forked mainnet and using the pools in there.

Now the question is, do I need real DAI and WETH tokens to test addLiquidity functionality?

Answer (score 1):

No, you dont need real DAI or any other token. You just need to fork and use any address that has enough tokens.

For example:

Get an address of account that has large amount of ether. [Here](https://etherscan.io/token/0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f#balances) is a list of holders of DAI token.  Just pick one and use this address when creating transaction or deploying contract.